# How Can I get the source code for Android's Google Maps application?

Tags: android, google-maps

I read somewhere that all default android applications where opensource.

And i also Use Android Home Screen Launcher Code from the Android Original Source code which is open Source for all.

So As like this i cant get Google Maps Source code from the Android open Source code?

Thanks

S_k

Comment: I think that not all are open sourced.... The only ones I've look into their code are Contacts and MyTracks

Comment: @mccrank i already used Home screen launcher, so its open Sourced and Google Maps App is not open sourced?

Comment: I think it's not and I dind't know that Home Screen Launcher was open sourced. Could you give me a link? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read somewhere that all default android applications where opensource.

You are incorrect.

> So As like this i cant get Google Maps Source code from the Android open Source code?

Correct. The Google Maps application is a commercial application, as is the Android Market, Gmail, YouTube, and various others.